# create JSON from 2 arrays in IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, nsdictionary

I'm trying to create dictionary to POST JSON data to server:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"lat", @"lon", nil];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: orderClass.extraLat, orderClass.extraLon, nil];
NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
```

this gives me:

```
{
    lat =     (
        "54.720746",
        "54.719206",
        "54.717466"
    );
    lon =     (
        "56.011108",
        "56.008510",
        "56.007031"
    );
}
```

But the aim is to POST data from arrays in format:

```
[{"lat":"54.720746", "lon":"56.011108" },
 { "lat":"54.719206", "lon":"56.008510"},
 { "lat":"54.717466", "lon":"56.007031"}]
```

Need your help.
Thanks for paying attention!

Comment: You're creating a dictionary with two arrays. You need to create array with three (in your example, 'n' in general...) dictionaries. Switch the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment - you need to reverse the steps towards your goal. First dictionaries, then array. And you'll get what you want.

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"lat", @"lon", nil];
NSArray *lats = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];
NSArray *lons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"5", @"6", nil];

// your way (not what you want)
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: lats, lons, nil];
NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

// my recommendation based on what you want
NSMutableArray *postData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < lats.count; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:[lats objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"lat"];
    [dict setObject:[lons objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"lon"];
    [postData addObject:dict];
}
```

This will get you these results:

```
(lldb) po postDict
{
    lat =     (
        1,
        2,
        3
    );
    lon =     (
        4,
        5,
        6
    );
}
```

And

```
(lldb) po postData
<__NSArrayM 0x7ffb5be4d950>(
{
    lat = 1;
    lon = 4;
},
{
    lat = 2;
    lon = 5;
},
{
    lat = 3;
    lon = 6;
}
)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! The goal is achieved!